# Expanding div within a dialog page results in content displaying incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a page within an iFrame that displays in a jQuery UI dialog box. On that page I have a div that is dynamically filled with content after a user does a search. Once the content is filled I have a link that allows them to "View All" or "View Less." When the view all option is clicked, I set the overflow on the div to visible, and when the view less option is clicked, it is set back to hidden with a fixed height on the div. The problem is that when the overflow is switched to visible, the content does not display correctly. Sometimes is shows random blocks, and sometimes it shows nothing at all. Once I scroll down, the content shows up correctly. What would cause my div to not display correctly? Below I have included the block from my javascript file, and images of the div. The first image is the collapsed div; second is the div displaying incorrectly; third is what the div should look like (shows up after scrolling).

HTML:

```
<div id="divBrandResults" class="div-bottom-Margin" runat="server">
      <div class="resultTitle">
           <asp:Label ID="lblBrandResults" Text="Filter Results by Brand" CssClass="bold-Label-Text" runat="server" />
           <div id="divToggleBrands" class="triggerToggleDivs">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblToggleBrands" Text="View All" runat="server" />
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="results">
           <div id="divInsertBrandResults" class="toggleExpandDivs" runat="server" style="height: 21px;">
           </div>
           <div style="clear: both; max-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both; max-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("div[id$=divToggleBrands]").click(function () {
if ($("span[id$=lblToggleBrands]").text() == "View All") {
    $("div[id$=divInsertBrandResults]").css('overflow', 'visible');
    $("span[id$=lblToggleBrands]").text("View Less");
} else {
    $("div[id$=divInsertBrandResults]").css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $("span[id$=lblToggleBrands]").text("View All");
}
});
```

CSS:

```
.toggleExpandDivs {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.triggerToggleDivs {
    color: #000066;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 10%;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: .9em;
}
```

[image: collapsed div]

[image: expanded div display problem]

[image: expanded div correct display]

Comment: IF you want us to help u, you may need to share more code like html and CSS... only the necessary to reproduce the problem. Also a live example on jsfiddle or codepen is the best

Comment: Edited. In addition to scrolling causing the text to appear, it will also appear after the mouse cursor is dragged over it. All the data is there, it just isn't showing up in the div once the overflow is changed.